# Modify SSH Warning: Root Login Not Permitted

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, rhel

I'm attempting to modify the SSH warning thrown out by an Amazon instance while logging in as root.

This is what I get:
"Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root"."

Where is this file location stored in RHEL 6.5?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
# this will create file sshd_banner
echo -e "You are not allowed to login using root." >> /etc/ssh/sshd_banner
echo "Please, use 'ec2-user' instead." >> /etc/ssh/sshd_banner
```

After that manually edit sshd_config file, *edit* the path to the banner file you've created earlier:

`Banner /etc/ssh/sshd-banner`

And of course, don't forget to restart sshd.

Try to search for this warning string using grep:

```
grep -rn ec2.user /etc/ssh
```

Comment: Hm. I attempted to make those changes - However, the banner method doesn't seem to get rid of the previous warning I'm dealing with. It's just echoed out in a new line after the banner.

Comment: Ooh, I misread it, actually, sorry. Try to make a search:  grep -rn ec2.user /etc/ssh/